# Is any set containing R infinite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Seriously. If I have a set say {R, Z, {}} what is its cardinality? Is it infinite since the set contains R(or possibly a better reason?)or is it countable? Why?

Comment: It has exactly $3$ elements: $\Bbb R$ is one of them, $\Bbb Z$ is another, and $\varnothing$ is the third.

Comment: Do not confuse yourself with thinking of elements of elements mattering, we only look "one level down", no more.  Although $\Bbb R$ has uncountably infinitely many elements, none of those elements of $\Bbb R$ are actually elements of your set in question.

Comment: If $R \subset X $ then X is "clearly" infinite.  But this is **VERY** impotant.  $R \in X $ is **!!!!!!!NOT!!!!!!!!** the same thing as $R\subset X $.  Your set {R,Z, {}} has finite cardinality of 3; it only has 3 elements!.  {R} is finite with cardinality 1.  It has *exactly* one and only one element.

Comment: @fleablood Given that ! means negation in C++, it would be difficult to keep track of what !!!!!!!NOT!!!!!!!! means :) (Also, the OP never specified what they meant by $R$, so it is not clear that $R\subset X$ clearly implies that $X$ is infinite, perhaps $R$ is finite or empty? ;)